# Can't send mail using JavaMail and Amazon SES using SMTP

Tags: java, email, amazon-web-services, smtp, jakarta-mail

I am trying to send an email through Amazon SMTP using JavaMail (1.4.7).

Here's my code

```
import java.util.Properties;

import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Transport;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;

public class AmazonSESSample {

        static final String FROM = "noreply@corp.com";
        static final String TO = "me@corp.com";

        static final String BODY = "this is the body";
        static final String SUBJECT = "hello test";
        static final String USER = "...";
        static final String PASS = "...";

        // Port we will connect to on the Amazon SES SMTP endpoint. We are choosing port 25 because we will use
        // STARTTLS to encrypt the connection.
        static final int PORT = 465;
        static final String PROTOCOL = "smtps";
        static final String HOST = "email-smtp.us-west-2.amazonaws.com";

        public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

                // Create a Properties object to contain connection configuration information.
                Properties props = System.getProperties();
                props.put("mail.transport.protocol", PROTOCOL);
                props.put("mail.smtps.host", HOST);
                props.put("mail.smtps.port", PORT); 
                props.put("mail.smtps.user", FROM);
                props.put("mail.debug","true");

                // Set properties indicating that we want to use STARTTLS to encrypt the connection.
                // The SMTP session will begin on an unencrypted connection, and then the client
                // will issue a STARTTLS command to upgrade to an encrypted connection.
//        props.put("mail.smtps.auth", "true");
//        props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
//        props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.required", "true");
//        props.put("mail.smtps.ssl.enable", "true");

                // Create a Session object to represent a mail session with the specified properties. 
                Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props);
                session.setDebug(true);

                // Create a message with the specified information. 
                MimeMessage msg = new MimeMessage(session);
                msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(FROM));
                msg.setRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(TO));
                msg.setSubject(SUBJECT);
                msg.setContent(BODY,"text/plain");
                //msg.saveChanges();

                // Create a transport.        
                Transport transport = session.getTransport("smtps");

                // Send the message.
                try
                {
                        System.out.println("connecting...");

                        // Connect to Amazon SES using the SMTP username and password you specified above.
                        transport.connect(HOST, USER, PASS);
                        System.out.println("connected");
                        // Send the email.
                        System.out.println("sending...");
                        transport.sendMessage(msg, msg.getAllRecipients());

                        System.out.println("Email sent!");
                }
                catch (Exception ex) {
                        System.out.println("The email was not sent.");
                        System.out.println("Error message: " + ex.getMessage());
                }
                finally
                {
                        // Close and terminate the connection.
                        transport.close();          
                }
        }
}
```

I get two types of errors sporadically.

sometimes I get "421 Timeout waiting for data from client":

```
DEBUG: JavaMail version 1.4.7
DEBUG: URL jar:file:/Users/adavid/.m2/repository/com/amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-ses/1.9.23/aws-java-sdk-ses-1.9.23.jar!/META-INF/javamail.providers
DEBUG: Bad provider entry: 
DEBUG: successfully loaded resource: jar:file:/Users/adavid/.m2/repository/com/amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-ses/1.9.23/aws-java-sdk-ses-1.9.23.jar!/META-INF/javamail.providers
DEBUG: successfully loaded resource: /META-INF/javamail.default.providers
DEBUG: Tables of loaded providers
DEBUG: Providers Listed By Class Name: {com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSSLTransport=javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtps,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSSLTransport,Oracle], com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport=javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtp,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport,Oracle], com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPSSLStore=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imaps,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPSSLStore,Oracle], com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3SSLStore=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,pop3s,com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3SSLStore,Oracle], com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imap,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore,Oracle], com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Store=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,pop3,com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Store,Oracle], com.amazonaws.services.simpleemail.AWSJavaMailTransport=javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,aws,com.amazonaws.services.simpleemail.AWSJavaMailTransport,Amazon Web Services LLC]}
DEBUG: Providers Listed By Protocol: {imaps=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imaps,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPSSLStore,Oracle], imap=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imap,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore,Oracle], smtps=javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtps,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSSLTransport,Oracle], pop3=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,pop3,com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Store,Oracle], pop3s=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,pop3s,com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3SSLStore,Oracle], smtp=javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtp,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport,Oracle], aws=javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,aws,com.amazonaws.services.simpleemail.AWSJavaMailTransport,Amazon Web Services LLC]}
DEBUG: successfully loaded resource: /META-INF/javamail.default.address.map
DEBUG: setDebug: JavaMail version 1.4.7
DEBUG: getProvider() returning javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtps,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSSLTransport,Oracle]
connecting...
DEBUG SMTP: useEhlo true, useAuth false
DEBUG SMTP: trying to connect to host "email-smtp.us-west-2.amazonaws.com", port 465, isSSL true
220 email-smtp.amazonaws.com ESMTP SimpleEmailService-1062959777 MTyV0IkyBqUpkEgbX2Av
DEBUG SMTP: connected to host "email-smtp.us-west-2.amazonaws.com", port: 465

EHLO 10.8.1.217
250-email-smtp.amazonaws.com
250-8BITMIME
250-SIZE 10485760
250-AUTH PLAIN LOGIN
250 Ok
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "8BITMIME", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "SIZE", arg "10485760"
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "AUTH", arg "PLAIN LOGIN"
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "Ok", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Attempt to authenticate using mechanisms: LOGIN PLAIN DIGEST-MD5 NTLM 
DEBUG SMTP: AUTH LOGIN command trace suppressed
DEBUG SMTP: AUTH LOGIN succeeded
connected
sending...
DEBUG SMTP: use8bit false
MAIL FROM:<noreply@pingidentity.com>
250 Ok
RCPT TO:<adavid@pingidentity.com>
250 Ok
DEBUG SMTP: Verified Addresses
DEBUG SMTP:   adavid@pingidentity.com
DATA
354 End data with <CR><LF>.<CR><LF>
From: noreply@pingidentity.com
To: adavid@pingidentity.com
Message-ID: <1653497584.0.1432736817561.JavaMail.javamailuser@localhost>
Subject: hello test
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=us-ascii
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

this is the body
.
421 Timeout waiting for data from client.
DEBUG SMTP: got response code 421, with response: 421 Timeout waiting for data from client.

RSET
DEBUG SMTP: EOF: [EOF]
DEBUG SMTP: MessagingException while sending, THROW: 
com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSendFailedException: 421 Timeout waiting for data from client.

    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.issueSendCommand(SMTPTransport.java:2108)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.finishData(SMTPTransport.java:1889)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.sendMessage(SMTPTransport.java:1120)
    at AmazonSESSample.main(AmazonSESSample.java:68)
The email was not sent.
Error message: 421 Timeout waiting for data from client.

QUIT
Exception in thread "main" javax.mail.MessagingException: Can't send command to SMTP host;
    nested exception is:
    java.net.SocketException: Connection closed by remote host
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.sendCommand(SMTPTransport.java:2157)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.sendCommand(SMTPTransport.java:2144)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.close(SMTPTransport.java:1210)
    at AmazonSESSample.main(AmazonSESSample.java:79)
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection closed by remote host
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.checkWrite(SSLSocketImpl.java:1490)
    at sun.security.ssl.AppOutputStream.write(AppOutputStream.java:70)
    at com.sun.mail.util.TraceOutputStream.write(TraceOutputStream.java:128)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:82)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(BufferedOutputStream.java:140)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.sendCommand(SMTPTransport.java:2155)
    ... 3 more
```

and sometimes I get "EOF: [EOF]":

```
    DEBUG: JavaMail version 1.4.7
DEBUG: URL jar:file:/Users/adavid/.m2/repository/com/amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-ses/1.9.23/aws-java-sdk-ses-1.9.23.jar!/META-INF/javamail.providers
DEBUG: Bad provider entry: 
DEBUG: successfully loaded resource: jar:file:/Users/adavid/.m2/repository/com/amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-ses/1.9.23/aws-java-sdk-ses-1.9.23.jar!/META-INF/javamail.providers
DEBUG: successfully loaded resource: /META-INF/javamail.default.providers
DEBUG: Tables of loaded providers
DEBUG: Providers Listed By Class Name: {com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSSLTransport=javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtps,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSSLTransport,Oracle], com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport=javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtp,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport,Oracle], com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPSSLStore=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imaps,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPSSLStore,Oracle], com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3SSLStore=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,pop3s,com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3SSLStore,Oracle], com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imap,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore,Oracle], com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Store=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,pop3,com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Store,Oracle], com.amazonaws.services.simpleemail.AWSJavaMailTransport=javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,aws,com.amazonaws.services.simpleemail.AWSJavaMailTransport,Amazon Web Services LLC]}
DEBUG: Providers Listed By Protocol: {imaps=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imaps,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPSSLStore,Oracle], imap=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imap,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore,Oracle], smtps=javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtps,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSSLTransport,Oracle], pop3=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,pop3,com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Store,Oracle], pop3s=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,pop3s,com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3SSLStore,Oracle], smtp=javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtp,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport,Oracle], aws=javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,aws,com.amazonaws.services.simpleemail.AWSJavaMailTransport,Amazon Web Services LLC]}
DEBUG: successfully loaded resource: /META-INF/javamail.default.address.map
DEBUG: setDebug: JavaMail version 1.4.7
DEBUG: getProvider() returning javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtps,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSSLTransport,Oracle]
connecting...
DEBUG SMTP: useEhlo true, useAuth false
DEBUG SMTP: trying to connect to host "email-smtp.us-west-2.amazonaws.com", port 465, isSSL true
220 email-smtp.amazonaws.com ESMTP SimpleEmailService-1062893701 2HRiJbNHu9DYCQClBXLu
DEBUG SMTP: connected to host "email-smtp.us-west-2.amazonaws.com", port: 465

EHLO 10.8.1.217
421 Timeout waiting for data from client.
HELO 10.8.1.217
DEBUG SMTP: EOF: [EOF]
The email was not sent.
Error message: [EOF]
```

I'm missing something and I don't know what...

would appreciate any help with this

Comment: Amazon SMTP may have very stringent timeout requirements to prevent clients from wasting connections.  Perhaps your application or your virtual machine is suffering from scheduling delays that prevent it from responding quickly enough.  You might want to upgrade to the [current version of JavaMail](https://java.net/projects/javamail/pages/Home).  That would allow you to use java.util.logging for the debug output, which would allow you to get timestamped log entries, perhaps showing where the delay is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you try

```
System.setProperty("line.separator", "\r\n");
```

Just after setting your property to comply with [RFC 822](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc822.txt)

Comment: That should not be necessary.  JavaMail ensures that lines end with CRLF when sending with SMTP.

Comment: After re-checking it looks like the problem happens indeterminately only on my private development computer which is an OSX machine.
On Ubuntu, it's working with or without: System.setProperty("line.separator", "\r\n");

it could also be a network issue, since the Ubuntu test server is an AWS server.

Answer (score 1):

for the 421 client expcetion - I had the same issue. I solved it by verifing that the transport is connected:

```
 if (!transport.isConnected())//make sure the connection is alive
        transport.connect();
 transport.sendMessage(message, message.getAllRecipients());
```